# jquery unchecked checkboxes changes images

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Some details first:

I have 4 image place holders.
I have several checkboxes. Each checkbox is associated with an image. 
User is allowed to check off 4 boxes.

When a user clicks on a checkbox it replaces one of the image place holders with the image that was assoicated with the checkbox.

After the user checks off 4 of the check boxes, the rest of the chexkboxes become disabled.

So now we have the 4 image place holders populated with images from the checked check boxes.

Here is where my issue comes into play.

If the user decides to uncheck a box, i need the correct place holder image to go back to it's generic place holder image.

So if the 4 checkboxes the user checked were 1: Hammer 2: Screwdriver 3: Nails 4: Saw. Those 4 place holder images would be populated with a Hammer, Screwdrive, Nails and a Saw. If they decide to uncheck the Screwdriver checkbox then that placeholder image with the screwdrive should switch to the generic place holder image.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that.

thanks in advance!

```
function countChecked() {  

    var radioCandyCount = document.getElementsByName('HowManyCandies');

             for (var i = 0, length = radioCandyCount.length; i < length; i++) {
                if (radioCandyCount[i].checked) {

                var a = radioCandyCount[i].value;
                var b = "2";
                var c = Number(a) + Number(b);



        var n = $("input:checked").length; 

        document.getElementById("CandyCount").value = Number(c) - Number(n)
```

// DOES NOT WORK ....THIS SECTION IS TO REVERT THE PLACE HOLDER IMAGES BACK TO ITS GENERIC IMAGE... DOES NOT WORK

```
        if (document.getElementById("CandyCount").value == 4) {
            $('#Jar1').css("background-image", "url(/Images/SingleJar.png)");
            $('#Jar2').css("background-image", "url(/Images/SingleJar.png)");
            $('#Jar3').css("background-image", "url(/Images/SingleJar.png)");
            $('#Jar4').css("background-image", "url(/Images/SingleJar.png)");


        }
        if (document.getElementById("CandyCount").value == 3) {

            if ($(this).not(':checked')) {                

                var unChecked = this.value;                




                if ($('#Jar1').css("backgroundImage") == "url(\"/Images/" + unChecked + ".png\"" + ")");
                {
                    $('#Jar1').css("background-image", "url(/Images/SingleJar.png)");
                }
                if ($('#Jar2').css("backgroundImage") == "url(\"/Images/" + unChecked + ".png\"" + ")");
                {
                    $('#Jar2').css("background-image", "url(/Images/SingleJar.png)");
                }
                if ($('#Jar3').css("backgroundImage") == "url(\"/Images/" + unChecked + ".png\"" + ")");
                {
                    $('#Jar3').css("background-image", "url(/Images/SingleJar.png)");
                }
            }


        }
        if (document.getElementById("CandyCount").value == 2) {

            if ($(this).not(':checked')) {

                var unChecked = this.value;

                if ($('#Jar1').css("backgroundImage") == "url(\"/Images/" + unChecked + ".png\"" + ")");
                {
                    $('#Jar1').css("background-image", "url(/Images/SingleJar.png)");
                }
                if ($('#Jar2').css("backgroundImage") == "url(\"/Images/" + unChecked + ".png\"" + ")");
                {
                    $('#Jar2').css("background-image", "url(/Images/SingleJar.png)");
                }

            }


        }
        if (document.getElementById("CandyCount").value == 1) {

            if ($(this).not(':checked')) {


                var unChecked = this.value;


                if ($('#Jar1').css("backgroundImage") == "url(\"/Images/" + unChecked + ".png\"" + ")");
                {                       
                    $('#Jar1').css("background-image", "url(/SingleJar.png)");
                }

            }


        }

                    // *****END**** THIS SECTION IS TO REVERT THE PLACE HOLDER IMAGES BACK TO ITS GENERIC IMAGE *****END****


                    // THIS SECTION CHANGES THE PLACE HOLDER IMAGE BASED ON THE ASSOCIATED CHECKBOX IMAGE

        if (length == 3) {
            if (document.getElementById("CandyCount").value == 3) {
                $(':checkbox(:checked)')                    
                    if (this.checked) {                         
                        var CandyChoice = "url(" + "/Images/" + this.value + ".png )";                           
                        $('#Jar4').css("background-image", CandyChoice);
                    }

            }
            if (document.getElementById("CandyCount").value == 2) {
                $(':checkbox(:checked)')                    
                if (this.checked) {   
                        var CandyChoice = "url(" + "/Images/" + this.value + ".png )";                            
                        $('#Jar3').css("background-image", CandyChoice);
                    }

            }
            if (document.getElementById("CandyCount").value == 1) {
                $(':checkbox(:checked)')                    
                if (this.checked) {   
                        var CandyChoice = "url(" + "/Images/" + this.value + ".png )";                           
                        $('#Jar2').css("background-image", CandyChoice);
                    }

            }
            if (document.getElementById("CandyCount").value == 0) {
                $(':checkbox(:checked)')                    
                if (this.checked) {   
                        var CandyChoice = "url(" + "/Images/" + this.value + ".png )";                            
                        $('#Jar1').css("background-image", CandyChoice);
                    }

            }
        }

                    // *****END****  THIS SECTION CHANGES THE PLACE HOLDER IMAGE BASED ON THE ASSOCIATED CHECKBOX IMAGE  *****END**** 

         if (n == c)                                              
            {                                                        
                  $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);

                 document.getElementById('AddCart').style.display = 'inline';
                  $(document).scrollTop( $("#AddCart").offset().top );
                   $("#StepFourCheck").fadeIn('slow'); 

             }                                                        
         else                                                     
             {                                                        
           $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false); 

           document.getElementById('AddCart').style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById('StepFourCheck').style.display = 'none';



            }
            }
            }
            }
```

Comment: please post some code (jsfiddle), what have you tried?

Comment: The problem I am having is that it is replacing the wrong image place holder.

Comment: please make a full example with html here, http://jsfiddle.net/ its hard to debug without the actual code

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. never used it before. I have to run out for a few hours, as soon as I get back I will put one together. thanks a lot for your interest so far!

Comment: I've been trying to put it up on jsfiddle, but I haven't been able to get it to work. A lot of things don't work that normally work in my web browser.